# Tying in .addClass() with other functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Assuming an accordion dropdown with the standard form of:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <a href="#">Main Element</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href="#">Dropdown Element</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using jQuery to expand when the parent element link is clicked:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

function initMenus() {
    $j('ul.menu ul').hide();
    $j.each($j('ul.menu'), function(){
        $j('#' + this.id + '.expandfirst ul:first').show();
    });
    $j('ul.menu li a').click(
        function() {
            var checkElement = $j(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;

            if($j('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                $j(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
                return false;
            }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                if($j('#' + parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                    $j('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                }
                return false;
            }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $j('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
}
$j(document).ready(function() {initMenus();});
```

To add a class to the Main Element when clicked (aka the class is enabled anytime the dropdown is expanded) I'm trying to use .toggleClass(className) without luck, most likely to my positioning. Where can I add this element to get the desired effect?

Comment: To start, you're doing weird stuff with the parent - getting the ID using standard DOM, and then using jQuery to select it. Change `var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;` to `var parent = $j(this).parent().parent()`.

Comment: Then you can change selectors like `$j('#' + parent + ' ul:visible')` to `parent.find('ul:visible');`. `find()` is actually faster, and it will be less error-prone.

Comment: As noted below, I see the the .parent method is better than .parentNode in general and I appreciate the speed increase / error reduction but I'm still not seeing what I should then toggleClass with.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
```

with:

```
var parent = $j(this).parent().closest('a').attr('id');
```

And instead of:

```
$j(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
```

Try:

```
$j(this).parent().closest('a').slideToggle('normal');
```

The `closest` moves up to find the closest link which in your case is main link.

Comment: This does seem to be a better method but it doesn't seem to address the issue of adding a class to the parent element, which is the current issue I'm struggling with. I'm switching the code over from .parentNode to .parent.

Comment: You can add the class with `addClass` like this: `$j(this).parent().closest('a').addClass('class_name_here');`